# Setting GlassFish-Mysql Connection Pool on Openshift

Tags: mysql, jdbc, openshift, connection-pooling

I just created a new application with the DIY cartridge and add a MySQL cartridge to it as well. I also was able to deploy the application online.
I cannot use the GlassFish administration console with OpenShift but I need to set up JDBC resources, connection pools. I'm trying to edit the domains.xml of my remote glassfish server using that of my local glassfish server. I'm still unable to connect to the database. This is what I've done so far:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="SamplePool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      <property name="User" value="adminvcsHiYw"></property>
      <property name="DatabaseName" value="timetable"></property>
      <property name="serverName" value="127.8.28.2"></property>
      <property name="PortNumber" value="3306"></property>
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://127.8.28.2:3306/timetable"></property>
      <property name="Password" value="_R-LrpYIcdUf"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
```

This is the output of `rhc tail -a appname`

```
 ==> app-root/logs/mysql.log <==
150621  7:55:43 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150621  7:55:43  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150621  7:55:44 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 1686690
150621  7:55:44 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.8.28.2'; port: 3306
150621  7:55:44 [Note]   - '127.8.28.2' resolves to '127.8.28.2';
150621  7:55:44 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.8.28.2'.
150621  7:55:44 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@ex-std-node534.prod.rhcloud.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
150621  7:55:44 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150621  7:55:44 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/5585ff875004465b5500013a/mysql//socket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
`
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to host a java app running on a glassfish server using Openshift you have to:

- Clone from github the [glassfish DIY](https://github.com/svanimpe/glassfish-openshift/)  you are going to use.
  The domain.xml configuration file has been modified to run on OpenShift.
  It already includes the MySQL driver in domain1/lib. The archive also contains the start and stop hooks we need.
- In the application page select the Do-It-Yourself, DIY, cartridge [image]
- Fill it as shown on the picture below. You should nonetheless choose your app name and your domain.

  [image]
- You will need the [OpenShift Client Tools](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install)

---

*Configuration*

- Once the application is created clone it on your local machine say 
  `rhc git-clone diyapp` and move the glassfish4 directory (the entire directory, not just its contents) into `diyapp`/diy.
  Move the start and stop hooks into yourapp/.openshift/action_hooks and check to make sure they're executable. `chmod +x start stop`

`.
├── glassfish4
│   ├── bin
│   ├── glassfish
│   ├── javadb
│   ├── mq
│   └── pkg
├── README.md
├── start
└── stop`

- Now, add, commit and push the changes you made back to OpenShift:

  `cd diyapp`
  `git add .`
  `git status`
  `git commit -m "Added GlassFish"`
  `git push`
  The push will cause your application to restart and execute the new start hook.

---

*Deploying app*

- To deploy an application, simply copy its war into domain1/autodeploy and run the previous commands again to add, commit and push the changes. GlassFish will automatically deploy your application after launch. If you think something went wrong, use ssh to log into your application and look for a your.war_deployed file in the autodeploy directory:

  `rhc app ssh diyapp
  cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/
  cd diy/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/
  ls`

If there is no such file, take a look at the server logs to find out what went wrong:

`cd ../logs/
   cat server.log | tail -n100`

---

*set up JDBC resources, connection pools*

- Add a MySQL cartridge to your app.
- You cannot use the GlassFish administration console with OpenShift. Neither does glassfish-resources.xml seem to be supported.

Set up the resources you need on a local GlassFish server.
Take a look at that server's domain.xml to see what changes were made.
Make the same changes to domain1/config/domain.xml in yourapp.

This is what I added

```
 `<jdbc-connection-pool is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="SamplePool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
  <property name="User" value="adminvcsHiYw"></property>
  <property name="DatabaseName" value="timetable"></property>
  <property name="serverName" value="127.8.28.2"></property>
  <property name="PortNumber" value="3306"></property>
  <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://127.8.28.2:3306/timetable"></property>
  <property name="Password" value="_R-LrpYIcdUf"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

`
So the database name is that of the MySQL cartridge you are going to add. The port name is that of MYSQL, the user name and password are provided once you create the MYSQL cartidge.

- In your app now everywhere you placed localhost replace it by the value of
  `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.9.226.130`.

To find out that value, ssh into your application and write the command:

```
 `env | grep MYSQL`
```

As usual: add, commit and push the changes.

- That's it it you are done.

[References](http://svanimpe.be/blog/glassfish-openshift.html)